# Merge multidimensional Array PHP without changing the key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, array-merge

i have a problem to merge this array, I want to merge this array bellow

```
    Array
    (
       [0] => Array
           (
               [image] => logo.jpg
               [name] => data
               [server] => Mirani Rahmawati
               [6] => 5
           )

       [1] => Array
           (
               [image] => logo.jpg
               [name] => data
               [server] => Mirani Rahmawati
               [5] => 150
           )
       )
```

and the expected result will be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image] => logo.jpg
            [name] => data
            [server] => Mirani Rahmawati
            [6] => 5
            [5] => 150
        )

)
```

without changing the key..

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array Operators +` to do that. You can check my below demo:

```
<?php

$array = [
  array(
    "image" => "logo.jpg",
    "name" => "data",
    "server"=> "Mirani Rahmawati",
     "6" => "5"
  ),
  array(
    "image"=> "logo.jpg",
    "name" => "data",
    "server"=> "Mirani Rahmawati",
     "5" => "150"
  )
];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
   $result = $result + $item;
}

print_r($result);
exit;

?>
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [image] => logo.jpg
    [name] => data
    [server] => Mirani Rahmawati
    [6] => 5
    [5] => 150
)
```

You can find out more at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: Thnkyou, for answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array = array();
$array[]  = array(
    "image" => "logo.jpg",
    "name" => "data",
    "server" => "Mirani Rahmawati",
    6 => 5
);
$array[]  = array(
    "image" => "logo.jpg",
    "name" => "data",
    "server" => "Mirani Rahmawati",
    5 => 150    
);

$new_array = array($array[0] + $array[1]);
var_dump($new_array);
```

[Array Merge - Contribute Notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: thnkyou so much for your answer, this working too for my problem but @tartarus answer what i search for..